# How to pass an object in Python with the self keyword?

Tags: python

Is it possible to pass an object in Python such that the only reference to the object is the self keyword?

```py
class A:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 'A'
        
    def wave(self,friend):
        friend.make_friend(self)
        
        
class B:
    
    def __init__(self):
        val = 'B'
        
    def make_friend(self, friend):
        self.friend = friend
    
a = A
b = B    

a.wave(friend=B)

>>>
----> 1 a.wave(friend=B)

TypeError: A.wave() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

From this error, it does not appear to be possible. See class A method wave. This method intends to send A to B. But I can't reference A within A because it's simply an instance of the class. Thus, I want to pass it using the self keyword.

Comment: May be you miss the bracket `a = A()`?

Comment: there is also the `self` missing in your `class B` `val = 'B' ` in case you wanna call it at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible yes. You just happen to get that error due to not creating an instance of class A. To create an instance of a class, you need to call the class with parentheses.

```
a = A()
b = B()
a.wave(friend=b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue in your example is that you haven't instantiated either class. `a = A` is essentially saying 'a is another name for A', while `a = A()` means 'a is an instance of A'.

When you call class methods out in the open and not on an instance of the class like that, self is not bound for you. You can make the method static, or you can create an object.

Answer (score 2):

[From the Python docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

> Class instantiation uses function notation. Just pretend that the class object is a parameterless function that returns a new instance of the class.
> `x = MyClass()` creates a new instance of the class and assigns this object to the local variable x.

In your code snippet, you are not creating instances of these classes, hence the error that `self` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

so the error was you weren't creating the instance of the class, and you had some unused parameters

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 'A'
        
    def wave(self, friend):
        friend.make_friend(self)
        
        
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 'B'
        self.friend = None
        
    def make_friend(self, friend):
        self.friend = friend
    
a = A()
b = B()    

a.wave(friend=b)
print(b.friend.val) # Output: A
```

instead of `a = A`, it should be `a = A()` because you are making an instance of a class.

in the class `B` I changed the `val` to `self.val`,to make it accessible by other methods.

in the class `A` method `wave`, the parameter `friend` I changed it to `self` to make the `friend` of the class `A` an instance.

function `make_friend`, the `friend`  I added `self.friend = friend`.

I added a `print` to check if the the `friend` is set correctly.
now compile the code and it should output `A`, this would show that the `friend` of `b` is `a`.